# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.dao.UserDAO

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, primefaces

I'm trying to make this project of this link: http://uaihebert.com/full-web-application-with-tomcat-jsf-primefaces-jpa-hibernate/
When I try to run this application, appears this error:

> javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.dao.UserDAO
>       at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
>       at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
>       at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
>       at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
>       at com.filter.LoginCheckFilter.doFilter(LoginCheckFilter.java:61)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.dao.UserDAO
>       at com.facade.UserFacade.(UserFacade.java:17)
>       at com.mb.LoginMB.login(LoginMB.java:45)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
>       at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:289)
>       at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
>       at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
>       ... 41 more

UserDAO:

```
public class UserDAO extends GenericDAO<User> {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   public UserDAO() {
       super(User.class);
   }

   public User findUserByEmail(String email) {
       Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
       parameters.put("email", email);

       return super.findOneResult(User.FIND_BY_EMAIL, parameters);
   }
}
```

UserFacade:

```
public class UserFacade {
   private UserDAO userDAO = new UserDAO();

    public User isValidLogin(String email, String password) {
        userDAO.beginTransaction();
        User user = userDAO.findUserByEmail(email);

        if (user == null || !user.getPassword().equals(password)) {
            return null;
        }

        return user;
   }
}
```

User:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
@NamedQuery(name = "User.findUserByEmail", query = "select u from User u where u.email = :email")
public class User implements Serializable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   public static final String FIND_BY_EMAIL = "User.findUserByEmail";

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   private int id;

   @Column(unique = true)
   private String email;
   private String password;
   private String name;
   @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
   private Role role;

   public int getId() {
       return id;
   }

   public void setId(int id) {
       this.id = id;
   }

   public String getEmail() {
       return email;
   }

   public void setEmail(String email) {
       this.email = email;
   }

   public String getPassword() {
       return password;
   }

   public void setPassword(String password) {
       this.password = password;
   }

   public String getName() {
       return name;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
   }

   public Role getRole() {
       return role;
   }

   public void setRole(Role role) {
       this.role = role;
   }

   public boolean isAdmin() {
       return Role.ADMIN.equals(role);
   }

   public boolean isUser() {
       return Role.USER.equals(role);
   }

   @Override
   public int hashCode() {
       return getId();
   }

   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object obj) {
       if (obj instanceof User) {
           User user = (User) obj;
           return user.getId() == id;
       }

       return false;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this error is related with Class not found or libs not found, try reimport correct libs of Hibernate and JPA.

Download this on: http://hibernate.org/orm/

Unzip, and copy all jars from folder hibernate\lib\required for correct funcion of ORM Hibernate and copy all jars from hibernate\lib\jpa for include JPA.

Import on Build Path all jars (import external jars), done.

Comment: Thanks!!
This problem has been solved with this answer